# How to read .mht files on a Mac?

Tags: mac, internet-explorer, mht

I have a web page saved with Internet Explorer as an `.mht` file.

How do I view this on a Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Firefox/SeaMonkey, you could try using the [Mozilla Archive Format](http://maf.mozdev.org/index.html) Extension which should work on a Mac according the installation page:

> Mozilla Archive Format, at the time of
>   each release, is tested and verified
>   with the most recent browser versions
>   available in the following release
>   channels:
>
> ```
> Firefox 3.6
> Firefox Beta
> Firefox Release
> SeaMonkey 2.1
> ```
>
> Testing is done under Windows XP, but
>   the add-on is expected to work on all
>   the platforms supported by the
>   browser. Note that the add-on is only
>   declared compatible with versions of
>   Firefox and SeaMonkey on which it is
>   actually tested, thus excluding the
>   Nightly channel, though partial
>   compatibility might be implemented for
>   the Aurora channel. Users that would
>   like to experiment with using the
>   add-on on the Nightly or Aurora
>   channels should override the
>   compatibility declarations using the
>   Add-on Compatibility Reporter.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome can view .mht files too now, if you have a recent build.

Comment: Is this still true? If I open an MHT in Chrome 40 from file:// it displays the file but refuses to load the resources due to permissions problems (?!)  If I open it from http://, it displays the MHT source as literal text instead of rendering it.

Answer (score 1):

A cursory search shows that [the Opera browser](http://www.opera.com/download/index.dml?platform=mac) may open .mht files in OS X.

Some articles suggest [Graphic Converter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/) or [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/) may perform this function as well.